# Encode() not working in all cases

Tags: python, regex, unicode, encode

I am using Beautiful Soup 4 to scan through an html file and extract certain features. Specifically, I am using it to find soccer player names, clubs, leagues, stats, etc. Since many player and club names have accent marks I am looking for a way to print out these accent marks rather than seeing an output like "Kak\xe1" I was able to make it work by using

```
# open html page
fut_page = open('futhead1.html','r')
# read content from html page
fut_read = fut_page.read()
# html parsed page
fut_soup = BeautifulSoup(fut_read, "html.parser")
# grabs all players
players = fut_soup.findAll('li',{'class':'list-group-item list-group-table-row player-group-item dark-hover'})
player = players[2]
# name_tag contains tag with player's name
name_tag = player.find("span",{"class":"player-name"})
# extract just the player's name
player_name = name_tag.text
print player_name.encode('utf-8')
```

This prints out the proper player name: "Kaká" However, I do not see the same result when using a regex to extract the club name, for example

```
regex_club = re.compile(ur'\[.*?</strong>\\n\s+\|\s\\n\s+(.*?)\\n', re.MULTILINE)
# extract club name
player_club = re.match(regex_club, str(pos_clb_lge_tag))
print player_club.group(1).encode('utf-8')
```

This code works in printing out the proper club name, say, "Atl\xe9tico Madrid" but encode() does not work in getting rid of "\xe9" and replacing it with "é"

Below is the piece of the html file where I apply the regex

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-table-row player-group-item dark-hover">
<div class="content player-item font-24">
    <a class="display-block padding-0" href="/fifa-mobile/17/players/33194/jan-oblak/">
        <span class="player-rating stream-col-50 text-center">
            <span class="revision-gradient shadowed font-12 fut elite">100</span>
        </span>
        <span class="player-info">
            <img class="player-image" src="http://futhead.cursecdn.com/static/img/fm/17/players/200389_SASC.png">
            <img class="player-program" src="http://futhead.cursecdn.com/static/img/fm/17/resources/program_17_VSATTACK.png">
            <span class="player-name">Jan Oblak</span>
            <span class="player-club-league-name">
                <strong>GK</strong>
                 | 
                Atlético Madrid
                 | 
                LaLiga Santander
            </span>
        </span>

        <span class="player-right text-center hidden-xs">
            <span class="player-stat stream-col-60 hidden-md hidden-sm"><span class="value">83</span><span class="hover-label">PAC</span></span><span class="player-stat stream-col-60 hidden-md hidden-sm"><span class="value">50</span><span class="hover-label">SHO</span></span><span class="player-stat stream-col-60 hidden-md hidden-sm"><span class="value">66</span><span class="hover-label">PAS</span></span><span class="player-stat stream-col-60 hidden-md hidden-sm"><span class="value">55</span><span class="hover-label">DRI</span></span><span class="player-stat stream-col-60 hidden-md hidden-sm"><span class="value">58</span><span class="hover-label">DEF</span></span><span class="player-stat stream-col-60 hidden-md hidden-sm"><span class="value">85</span><span class="hover-label">PHY</span></span><span class="player-stat stream-col-60 font-12 font-medium text-upper">35</span>
        </span>
        <span class="player-right slide hidden-sm hidden-xs" data-direction="right" data-max="-482px">
            <span class="slide-content text-upper">
                <span class="trigger icon icon-dots-three-horizontal"></span>


                <span class="player-stat stream-col-80">
                    <span class="value">+2</span>
                    <span class="hover-label">MRK</span>
                </span>


                <span class="player-stat stream-col-80">
                    <span class="value">+1</span>
                    <span class="hover-label">OVR</span>
                </span>

                <span class="player-stat stream-col-100"><span class="value">right</span><span class="hover-label">Strong Foot</span></span>
                <span class="player-stat stream-col-100"><span class="value">18<span class="icon icon-star gold margin-l-4"></span></span><span class="hover-label">Weak Foot</span></span>
            </span>
        </span>

    </a>
</div>
```

So basically, why does encode() not work when I use a regex in the intermediate? If any further clarification is needed please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse tags?

Comment: In addition to the perplexing use of regex here to extract tags (you are already using BeautifulSoup!) it looks like you are playing fast-and-loose with string/unicode types. Stick to one. Or better yet, use Python 3.

Comment: In the "player-club-league-name" class how would I extract "Atletico Madrid" since it is embedded between two "|"? I am new to using Beautiful Soup and am just getting the hang of it and web scraping in general

Comment: I am using regex to parse this particular tag since the text I want is only part of the text that is in the tag. I want to get "Atletico Madrid" but the tag contains much more than that. Like I said, I just began using Beautiful Soup and couldn't find another way to extract what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you haven't shown all the code (see [mcve]), but calling `str` on the Unicode object is the wrong thing to do, and should have given:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I suspect you've done a `setdefaultencoding` which is a [bad habit](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/).

What `str()` did was convert the Unicode string into a byte string with escape code text, e.g. `'\\n'` (two characters) instead of `'\n'` (one character) and it did the same for the non-ascii character.

If your terminal is configured correctly you should not have to manually encode the final result when printing as well.

Here's a working example that uses BeautifulSoup to retrieve just the text to parse:

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# open html page
fut_page = open('futhead1.html','r')
# read content from html page
fut_read = fut_page.read()
# html parsed page
fut_soup = BeautifulSoup(fut_read, "html.parser")
# grabs all players
players = fut_soup.findAll('li',{'class':'list-group-item list-group-table-row player-group-item dark-hover'})
player = players[0]
# name_tag contains tag with player's name
name_tag = player.find("span",{"class":"player-club-league-name"})
# extract just the player's name
pos_clb_lge_tag = name_tag.contents[-1]
regex_club = re.compile(ur'\n\s+\|\s\n\s+(.*?)\n')
# extract club name
player_club = regex_club.match(pos_clb_lge_tag)
print player_club.group(1)
```

> Atlético Madrid

Comment: Thank you. I did not use setdefaultencoding and I did not receive an error. I programmed this on pycharm if that helps. The reason I used str() is because when I didn't it would give me an error saying    'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../futhead_scrape.py", line 41, in <module>
    player_pos = re.match(regex_pos, pos_clb_lge_tag)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 141, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer'

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this without regex? In the comments they were saying there was no need for regex since I was using Beautiful Soup already

Comment: I went a bit further with  Beautiful Soup to get the text, but then I used the regex like you did to break apart the text.  Your regex was parsing the content of the <strong> tag as well.  You could probably do a simple `.split('|')` and `.strip()` to break apart the text as well.